# Haskell function to keep the repeating elements of a list

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, filter

Here is the expected input/output:

> repeated "Mississippi" == "ips"
>
> repeated [1,2,3,4,2,5,6,7,1] == [1,2]
>
> repeated " "  ==  " "

And here is my code so far:

```
repeated :: String -> String
repeated "" = "" 
repeated x = group $ sort x
```

I know that the last part of the code doesn't work. I was thinking to sort the list then group it, then I wanted to make a filter on the list of list which are greater than 1, or something like that.

Comment: Sounds good so far. Do you have any questions?

Comment: I don't know how to filter the list of list, I always get an error. I was thinking to use this: `filter (\x -> length x > 1) ` or something like this.

Comment: That's step 1. There's still something you need to do afterwards (and you can see what you've got so far if you remove the (incorrect, by the way) type signature from `repeated`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, good start.  One immediate problem is that the specification requires the function to work on lists of numbers, but you define it for strings.  The list must be sorted, so its elements must have the typeclass `Ord`.  Therefore, let’s fix the type signature:

```
repeated :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
```

After calling `sort` and `group`, you will have a list of lists, `[[a]]`.  Let’s take your idea of using `filter`.  That works.  Your predicate should, as you said, check the `length` of each list in the list, then compare that `length` to 1.

Filtering a list of lists gives you a subset, which is another list of lists, of type `[[a]]`.  You need to flatten this list.  What you want to do is `map` each entry in the list of lists to one of its elements.  For example, the first.  There’s a function in the `Prelude` to do that.

So, you might fill in the following skeleton:

```
module Repeated (repeated) where

import Data.List (group, sort)

repeated :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
repeated = map _
         . filter (\x -> _)
         . group
         . sort
```

I’ve written this in point-free style with the filtering predicate as a lambda expression, but many other ways to write this are equally good.  Find one that you like!  (For example, you could also write the `filter` predicate in point-free style, as a composition of two functions: a comparison on the result of `length`.)

When you try to compile this, the compiler will tell you that there are two *typed holes*, the `_` entries to the right of the equal signs.  It will also tell you the type of the holes.  The first hole needs a function that takes a list and gives you back a single element.  The second hole needs a Boolean expression using `x`.  Fill these in correctly, and your program will work.

Answer (score 4):

Your code already does half of the job

```
> group $ sort "Mississippi"
["M","iiii","pp","ssss"]
```

You said you want to filter out the non-duplicates. Let's define a predicate which identifies the lists having at least two elements:

```
atLeastTwo :: [a] -> Bool
atLeastTwo (_:_:_) = True
atLeastTwo _       = False
```

Using this:

```
> filter atLeastTwo . group $ sort "Mississippi"
["iiii","pp","ssss"]
```

Good. Now, we need to take only the first element from such lists. Since the lists are non-empty, we can use `head` safely:

```
> map head . filter atLeastTwo . group $ sort "Mississippi"
"ips"
```

Alternatively, we could replace the filter with `filter (\xs -> length xs >= 2)` but this would be less efficient.

Yet another option is to use a list comprehension

```
> [ x | (x:_y:_) <- group $ sort "Mississippi" ]
"ips"
```

This pattern matches on the lists starting with `x` and having at least another element `_y`, combining the filter with taking the head.

Comment: Good answer, but it seems overkill to `group`: the q only cares if an element is repeated, not how many repeats. Then it also seems overkill to `sort` the whole list: it could sort after getting the elements wanted (and that would be much fewer). Would something similar to `nub` require less traversing of the list?

Comment: While it's true that sorting is O(n lg n), a linear traversal of an unsorted list will require some other data structure to keep track of all possible duplicates, and lookups in each will add to the space complexity at the very least. While carefully chosen data structures could be used to maintain an overall O(n) running time, the constant would probably make the algorithm slower in practice than the O(n lg n) solution, while greatly complicating the implementation.

Comment: @chepner I don't understand: `map head . filter p . group` should always be safe, for any `p`, since `group` never generates empty lists. The (non)presence of duplicates should not affect the safety of `map head` in this code. Have I overlooked some case?

Comment: Nope, I was just confusing empty lists with lists containing empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some other approaches, to evaluate @chepner's comment on the solution using `group $ sort`. (Those solutions look simpler, because some of the complexity is hidden in the library routines.)

> While it's true that sorting is O(n lg n), ...

It's not just the sorting but especially the `group`: that uses `span`, and both of them build and destroy temporary lists. I.e. they do this:

> a linear traversal of an unsorted list will require some other data structure to keep track of all possible duplicates, and lookups in each will add to the space complexity at the very least. While carefully chosen data structures could be used to maintain an overall O(n) running time, the constant would probably make the algorithm slower in practice than the O(n lg n) solution, ...

`group/span` adds considerably to that complexity, so O(n lg n) is not a correct measure.

> while greatly complicating the implementation.

The following all traverse the input list just once. Yes they build auxiliary lists. (Probably a `Set` would give better performance/quicker lookup.) They maybe look more complex, but to compare apples with apples look also at the code for `group/span`.

```
repeated2, repeated3, repeated4 :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
```

- `repeated2/inserter2` builds an auxiliary list of pairs `[(a, Bool)]`, in which the `Bool` is `True` if the `a` appears more than once, `False` if only once so far.

  ```
  repeated2 xs = sort $ map fst $ filter snd $ foldr inserter2 [] xs

  inserter2 :: Ord a => a -> [(a, Bool)] -> [(a, Bool)]
  inserter2 x [] = [(x, False)]
  inserter2 x (xb@(x', _): xs)
      | x == x'   = (x', True): xs
      | otherwise = xb: inserter2 x xs
  ```
- `repeated3/inserter3` builds an auxiliary list of pairs `[(a, Int)]`, in which the `Int` counts how many of the `a` appear. The aux list is sorted anyway, just for the heck of it.

  ```
  repeated3 xs = map fst $ filter ((> 1).snd) $ foldr inserter3 [] xs

  inserter3 :: Ord a => a -> [(a, Int)] -> [(a, Int)]
  inserter3 x [] = [(x, 1)]
  inserter3 x xss@(xc@(x', c): xs) = case x `compare` x' of
      { LT -> ((x, 1): xss)
      ; EQ -> ((x', c+1): xs)
      ; GT -> (xc: inserter3 x xs)
      }
  ```
- `repeated4/go4` builds an output list of elements known to repeat. It maintains an intermediate list of elements met once (so far) as it traverses the input list. If it meets a repeat: it adds that element to the output list; deletes it from  the intermediate list; filters that element out of the tail of the input list.

  ```
  repeated4 xs = sort $ go4 [] [] xs

  go4 :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
  go4 repeats _ [] = repeats
  go4 repeats onces (x: xs) = case findUpd x onces of
      { (True, oncesU) -> go4 (x: repeats) oncesU (filter (/= x) xs)
      ; (False, oncesU) -> go4 repeats oncesU xs
      }

  findUpd :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> (Bool, [a])
  findUpd x [] = (False, [x])
  findUpd x (x': os) | x == x' = (True, os)      -- i.e. x' removed
                     | otherwise =
                       let (b, os') = findUpd x os in (b, x': os')
  ```

  (That last bit of list-fiddling in `findUpd` is very similar to `span`.)